# What would be the best method for building Dynamic Reports from my SQL DB Data?

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio, data-warehouse, ssrs-2008-r2

I am building a simple database with about 6-7 tables. I will be setting a schedule to do a clean import from a .txt file.

I want to take this data and create a report, like I would do in an excel spreadsheet, convert it to a pdf and post it to our company intranet for those interested to access it.

I'm trying to think of the best way to build my report.  Would I just use an excel spreadsheet with a direct connection to the database? Would I create some sort of console application (c/c#/vb/vb.net) that would query the db, generate the report in an excel file, convert to pdf and save?

I'm quite comfortable in these different languages, just not as experienced in the reporting services (although I do have a lot of experience working with EXCEL and VBA Macros) but I want to get into it (SSRS) and get familiar with it as I will be doing a lot of projects like this in the future. This is seems like an easy one to get my hands dirty with and learn and build off of.

Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want to create a report in Excel, use PowerPivot. It allows advanced users to customize the report to some degree. If you want to publish the report on your company Intranet (presumably using Sharepoint), use SSRS.

Comment: How much data is involved?  Excel can work with a DB pretty well on it's own, as long as there's not too much data.  If there's a lot of data, then you'll want to add PowerPivot to Excel or look at other tools/approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experiences using a pivot table in Excel which is a connected table to your SQL database.

In the connection parameters in Excel there is a field where you can define your SQL query, whether it be to call a stored procedure or just a simple SELECT statement.

The main reason I prefer a pivot table SQL connection rather than a normal table connection is because if you have a chart that references the connected table, the chart formatting will be reset when you refresh your connection (if you need to updated your report).

If I use a chart that references a pivot table (or a pivot chart) then the formatting is retained.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

- Create desired SQL queries to retrieve the data in desired form
- Link these queries to your Excel sheet, perhaps directly in form of pivot tables for aggregation of results
- Using VBA, you can easily create PDF from the data at the click of a button

The initial design will be time intensive, but after that, everything is automated and one just needs to press the button that creates the PDF.

How to link Access queries to your Excel file:
Data --> Get external Data

You can easily refresh all data whenever you open the Excelsheet by using the code below in the On Open event of the workbook:

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

If you need further clarification, do not hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to create a PDF that will be out on your intranet then I would create the report in SSRS.  Then you can schedule it to run and output a PDF to your network location.